# Can't find variable: file with axios image uploading

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, image-uploading

I read that axios is good for image uploading to the database and here is what I got so far:

```
var photo = {
  uri: this.state.userimgSource,
  type: this.state.userimgSourceType,
  name: file, <-- here
  fileName: Image.png
};
var body = new FormData();
body.append('file', photo);
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `https://www.example.com/React/user-image-upload.php`,
    data: body,
    config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
})
```

I am new to Axios and I am not sure why I am getting `Can't find variable: file`.  I tried to put `file` into a string and react native will not accept that. If file needs to be a variable, what would I define it with?

Comment: You need to add headers like headers: {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`,
  }. If this does not work then you can look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663961/how-do-you-send-images-to-node-js-with-axios

Comment: i don't understand why you need to put file into name ?

Comment: `name: file` should that the place of `$_FILES['uploaded_file']` in my `upload.php` @SelmiKarim

Comment: @SaurabhGhewari Also, I did everything you did along with that SO Answer and I am still getting that error.

Comment: What is the difference between name and fileName? Does it have anything to do with it.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal `name` is similar to HTML's `name` when you want to use (for php to my knowledge) server side things and `fileName` is just the name of the image file