# Unable to upload image (React native, Laravel)

Tags: ios, laravel, react-native, axios

I have been trying this for a while but no success

Back-end

```
public function createInspection(Request $request) {
   $path = Storage::disk('public')->putFile('bin_images', new File($request->file('image')));
   return $path;    
}
```

Client

```
data.append("image", {
  uri: this.state.images[0].path,
  type: this.state.images[0].mime,
  size: this.state.images[0].size,
  name: filename
});

this.props.sendInspection(data)
```

Service (shortend)

```
const res = await axios.post(url, data, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  });
```

im not sure if it's something to do with path not being recongnized (ios image path) e.g. path :
`/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B6FEB0FD-F9C8-4088-B15F-99D27A818C76/tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/7BD81594-30E0-4E00-919C-4F353BBDE46F.jpg`

I get this error

`message: "The file "" does not exist", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException", file: "/Users/ysr/tza-project/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php", line: 37, file: "/Users/ysr/tza-project/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/MimeType/MimeTypeGuesser.php", line: 116`

Comment: can you do this
```php
public function createInspection(Request $request) {  
dd($request->allFiles());
}
```
what does it show to you?

Comment: I think you've googled, but still check this issues https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23492#issuecomment-372127261

so on the frontend, check file size - show it to us
on the backend, check file size - show it to us
on the backend, print `phpinfo()` (for example in your index.php before everything) and show variables like settings `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`

Answer (score 1):

the problem seems to be with your backend, check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#storing-files).

you should do something like this:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $path = $request->file('image')->store('images');

    return $path;
}
```

and in case you wanna use `putFile` then may use:

```
$path = Storage::putFile('images', $request->file('image'));
```

and if it needs to change the disk then:

```
$path = Storage::disk('public')->putFile('images', $request->file('image'));
```

Comment: I tried all too but still the same error. I even switched to `fetch` still the same error. Not sure what else to do!

Comment: Have you got your file in back end?
You may determine if a file is present on the request using the hasFile method:
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) { dump('some thing') }

Answer (score 0):

I don't know react very well but it seems that you are passing only image properties but not image file or image data in bytes.

Try changing your code:

```
data.append("image", {
  uri: this.state.images[0].path,
  type: this.state.images[0].mime,
  size: this.state.images[0].size,
  name: filename
});
```

To this code:

```
data.append("image", {
  file: this.state.images[0],
  uri: this.state.images[0].path,
  type: this.state.images[0].mime,
  size: this.state.images[0].size,
  name: filename
});
```

or also try changing `Content-Type` to `'multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}'`

If your image is base64 then you need to do few changes in API as below:

```
$path = 'bin_images/file_name.jpeg';
$image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $request->image);
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
Storage::put($path, base64_decode($image));
```

Comment: is `file` here the base64 data ?

Comment: No. File should be the actual uploaded file (in bytes format, not base64).

Comment: If you have base64 than change `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Please have a look into this thread. It might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663961/how-do-you-send-images-to-node-js-with-axios