# network request failed in react native fetch with form data

Tags: react-native, file-upload, fetch, multipartform-data

i'm trying to post recorded audio file to server using react native 0.59.8 and android. but getting error:
"network request failed", after searching found some solution like:
adding "android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"" to manifest file
but it failed again.
some post mentioned about adding "flipper" to mainapplication.java but i didn't try it.
my function:

```
        var body = new FormData()
        body.append('clipId', clipId);
        body.append('audio', file);
        console.log(body);
        let callRep = await fetch('https://url', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'token': user.Token
            },
            body: body
        });
        let rep = await callRep.json();
        console.log(rep);
```

why it's not posting like postman?

Comment: it is the problem of flipper

Comment: here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64445645/8798220

Comment: i saw the post, but i didn't see any line of code i"initializeFlipper" at mainapplication .java!?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551#issuecomment-611085378 ?

Comment: as saied before, i dont see any reactnativeflipper.java in project. are you sure it exist in rn version 59.8

Comment: react & native version?

Comment: sorry, a lot of time passed since then, but i think issue was with emulator