# How to store image object directly in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, image

I am passing image object array in my axios post request to node js server as below:

[image]

How can I store this image array object directly into mongodb so that I can retrieve i later as well and show it on UI?

Comment: This question appears to have been asked before here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663961/how-do-you-send-images-to-node-js-with-axios#44204752

Comment: GridFS with MongoDB