# I'm getting error while uploading image in multi step form of Formik using Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: Error image]

This is my image JSON which is returned from filereader. I'm using multer in backend to upload image.

[image: json image]

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me. How exactly can we help you?

Comment: You might wanna provide the code you are using and maybe some more info of the failed request

Comment: How can I upload the image? It just returns that error and when I check console.log(req.body), it shows image: [object, object] @FelixKling

Comment: Maybe this helps: [How do you send images to node js with Axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39663961/218196)

Comment: I'm using this as my multi step form https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-step-file-upload-with-preview-formik-9g6n4 But image don't get uploaded to my backend and returns above question mentioned error.. @FelixKling